# Direct3D COM interop in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

I noticed that Direct3D is COM exposed, but there doesn't seem to be a type library for it.

My first question is, what is the point of COM exposure if the infrastructure to use it isn't really there?

I've considered that I could write my own COM interfaces in C#. But it makes me somewhat concerned that this hasn't already been done, a lot. Any way you spin it, you have to do some sort of interop wrapper if you plan to use D3D in with .net. Why create a c++/cli wrapper or a dll export wrapper that is designed to be P/Invoked when you could just do COM interop and never leave C#? I assume there is probably a good reason for this, or there would already be libraries out there that use this methodology.

I'm fully aware of SlimDX and Windows API Code Pack. I am specifically interested in C# COM interop directly with Direct3D.

I noticed the MDXGI (codeplex) library, which attempts to do this methodology for DXGI, but it doesn't seem to be complete or getting much community response.

I also saw this related question ( [Is there COM exposure for Direct3D 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833642/is-there-com-exposure-for-direct3d-10) ), but I felt my question was at least a little bit different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to note that MS is no longer supporting managed use of Direct3D. For .Net there is Microsoft's XNA framework (http://creators.xna.com/en-US/), which is quite an abstraction from D3D itself, but does support Windows, Xbox360 and Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

Im an author of MDXGI project. As you see pure C# wrapper has some technical problems and no support of comunity.